# Why does VC++ 2013 not support non-static data member initializers as promised

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-errors, language-features

According to [C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), VC++ 2013 now supports non-static data member initializers.

However, the following code is rejected by VC++ 2013:

```
struct A
{
    const int n = 0; // error C2864
};
```

**error C2864: 'A::n' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class**

What's the root cause? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: I think it means the actual release. [This](http://www.infoq.com/resource/news/2013/07/vs2013_CPP_compliance/en/resources/VC_Roadmap.png) says RTM.

Comment: "Have you tried LLVM?"

Comment: @chris: At the top of the link it says, `The following table lists C++11 core language features and their implementation status in..Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013 Preview`, so it looks like a documentation bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the root cause? Is it a compiler bug?

It's a documentation bug, both [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx) and chris's link in the comment say that Non-static data member initializers will be implemented in VS2013 RTM.

Don't be surprised when you find false info on MSDN, there is a lot of old material, etc. which no one has updated or somebody made a mistake when typing it in.